# .Net Core 2.0 Web Api circular dependency after moving database context to DAL class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am making a Web Api that makes use of the Microsoft Identity service. To create a more maintainable project I decided to create a DAL(Data Acces Layer) project that is a simple class library, to make my code more compartmentalized.

I moved my dbcontext that inherits from IdentityDbContext to the DAL project. My BLL(Buissness Logic Layer) has a reference to my DAL so it can call the functions in my DAL, but because my dbcontext inherits from IdentityDbContext I need a reference in my BLL to my DAL so I can add the dbcontext service in my startup class, which ofcourse creates a circular dependency.

so my questions are

1. Is it seen as a good practice to move your database context to your DAL?
2. If so, how could I solve my problem so I dont need a reference from my DAL to 
   my BLL?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a reference from your DAL to your BLL. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: `my dbcontext inherits from IdentityDbContext I need a reference in my BLL to my DAL`  Could you show us which part of the code from BLL references DAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data context belongs in the data access layer, should you follow the approach.  However, depending on how you implement via the clean architecture (fancy terminology for onion architecture) or N-Tier architecture.  The two approaches are designed to create a separation of concerns, however clean architecture often is even more abstracted and loosely coupled than a typical N-Tier architecture.

The foundational approach though for your dependencies N-Tier would be along the following:

Data Access Layer:

- Domain Layer (Plain Old C# Objects)

Service Layer (Optional):

- Data Access Layer
- Domain Layer

Presentation Layer:

- Service Layer

However, if your incorporating in a framework such as Asp.Net Core you'll notice that your solution relies on middleware.  The presentation layer for a module, controller, view all reside in the solution file.  So you inadvertently would have a presentation layer to handle your UX, but will require your `IServiceCollection` to register those other dependencies creating a layer in line with:

Presentation Layer:

- Data Access Layer
- Domain Layer
- Service Layer

This will resolve the circular dependency issue, but then you have to decide on your coupling approach.  But this is the most common and barebones example you'll often see.

Data Access Layer:

```
public interface ISampleRepository : IDisposable
{
     IEnumerable<SampleModel> GetAllSamples();
}

public class SampleContext : ISampleRepository
{
     public IEnumerable<SampleModel> GetAllSamples()
     {
          // Implementation
     }
}

public interface ISampleFactory
{
     ISampleRepository Create();
}

public class SampleFactory
{
     ISampleRepository Create() => new SampleContext();
}
```

Service Layer:

```
public class SampleService
{
     IEnumerable<SampleModel> RetrieveSamples()
     {
          using(var context = new SampleFactory().Create())
               return context.GetAllSamples();
     }
}
```

Presentation Layer:

```
public class SampleController
{
     public JsonResult Index() => new JsonResult(new SampleService().RetrieveSamples());
}
```

You could use Dependency Injection or whatever, but this is a basic approach to help show you how the structure is designed to work within.  No solution is perfect, choose what fits your application requirements, don't add additional complexity unless it is to solve a legitimate issue, but hopefully this helps you understand.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that's where it belongs. However, how you define layer can vary which can leave you with varying project structures. I'd put the context in its own library and then create a DAL in a separate library and have the data context library be referenced only from the DAL project and none others, but that's unrelated to the issue at hand.
2. Refactor your layers and API to consume interfaces of each other instead of concrete classes. Place those interfaces in their own class libraries. Reference those interface class libraries both from the layers providing their implementations and the API/layers consuming them. Remove references to the libraries providing the concrete implementations themselves from the consumers. Wherever you wire up the dependencies (either in your API or in your injection/IOC library if you have one), reference both the interface and implementation libraries. As long as those interfaces don't have any complex dependencies and your IOC layer or API aren't referenced in any odd ways that should be enough to resolve your circular dependency issues. If your interfaces need to reference each other you'll need to put them both interfaces in the same library or refactor your interfaces further to reduce that coupling.